# Grails: Supplying Data to a Global UI Element

Tags: grails, groovy

Please pardon this newbie question...

In Grails, if I want a partial to be embedded in a layout so that it appears globally, which requires live data, let's say a list of categories, where is the best place to pull the category data to feed it into the view?

I realize this is a very basic question, but I haven't seen this covered in any tutorials yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started this as a comment to Bill James's answer but I figured it might be longer. Bill suggeseted using groovy code inside ${} to make the template (called partial in Rails) work globally:

```
<g:each in="${ Category.findAll() }" var="cat" />
```

But, you should not just add code if you dont feel like it might mess up your tidy xml/html. You can always put it in a closure inside a TagLib and thus make it a Tag. The closure must have no parameters, or an 'attr' parameter, or an 'attr' and 'body' parameters but other signatures are invalid.

```
class CustomTagLib {

 static namespace = 'cus'

    def categories = { attr, body ->
      g.each( in: Category.findAll(), var: attr?.var ?: 'categories' )
    }

}
```

Then you can use that tag into the template with the namespace you chose:

```
<cus:categories />
```

Personally I prefer using tags since most of the time it is a reusable code, so it's better for not violating the DRY principle.

Comment: Thanks Azder. Both approaches work obviously, but your taglib approach feels more MVC "correct", so I'm going to go with that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You want to put it in grails-app\views\layouts\main.gsp.  That's the default layout that most generated code (and likely most examples that you'll see) will use.

Check out the [sitemesh](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.2.4%20Layouts%20with%20Sitemesh) section of the grails documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to ask... "How do I feed the category data to the view when I don't know which action caused the page to render, so the action can't add the data to the model?"   If that's so, you can use Groovy code directly in the ${} block, such as:

```
<g:each in="${ Category.findAll() }" var="cat" />
```

Note that findAll is added to every Model class, and can be called statically (via the classname, not an instance).

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Bill. I thought of that, but wasn't sure if it was appropriate to call a method in the model directly from a view.

Comment: Well, it's not the strictest MVC, but it's not like you're putting the SQL in there.  You'll find the sample Grails stuff does this all the time.